# PHP mySQL LOAD LOCAL INFILE importing exactly half?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im trying to import some csv and tab deliminated txt feeds into my database using a php script. They all seem to work except this one.

I have a base php script that includes the database connection, disables keys, imports each feed (via an include statement) and re-enables keys, before then exporting the end results.

The feed that is causing me issues is this one, or should i say the sql statement.

```
$sql = "

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '../feeds/feed6.txt'
INTO TABLE supplierimport
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4,@col5,@col6,@col7,@col8,@col9,@col10,@col11,@col12,@col13,@col14,@col15,@col16)
SET
DistributorID = 546, MPN=@col1, Brand=@col6, DistributorSKU=@col1, `Condition`=@col15, ProductName=@col2, Cost= replace(@col4, ',', ''), Stock=@col5, EAN=@col12, ImageURL=@col11, ETA=@col7";

database_queryModify($sql,$result);

print "Imported...";
```

So, two questions on this one:

1. Is using this statement correct; `Cost= replace(@col4, ',', ''),` The reason i am using this statement is because i import the cost from each supplier into the column `cost` in my DB, but this particular supplier uses thousand separator, ie `1000.53` is displayed in the feed as `1,000.53` and therefore is not importing into my DB correctly, so i found the replace function, but wanted to verify that im using it correctly in this context?
2. Exactly half the rows in the file are being imported into my DB. I found this question; [mysql load data local infile syntax issues with set fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600134/mysql-load-data-local-infile-syntax-issues-with-set-fields) as you can see i have put \r\n, but it still does not import all.

Can anyone help.

Thanks

EDIT: Just three rows in the comma deliminated text file as an example. This was pasted as is from the file, thus i did not put the extra line in between each line. Also, the 3rd row, you will see that the price is "1,117.00" to show how the thousand separators are working:

```
"Item No.","Description","Description 2","Customers Price","Home stock","Brand Name","Expected date for delivery","Item Group No.","Item Group Name","Item Product Link (Web)","Item Picture Link (Web)","EAN/UPC","Weight","UNSPSC code","Product type code","Warranty"

"/5PL0006","Drum Unit","DK-23","126.00","32","Kyocera","03/11/2013","800002","Drums","http://uk.product.com/product.aspx?id=%2f5PL0006","http://s.pic.eu/products/2_PICTURE-TAKEN.JPG","5711045360824","0.30","44103109","","3M"

"/DK24","DK-24 Drum Unit FS-3750","","1,117.00","8","Dell","07/11/2013","800002","Drums","http://uk.product.com/product.aspx?id=%2fDK24","http://s.pic.eu/products/2_PICTURE-TAKEN.JPG","5711045360718","0.20","44103109","","3M"
```

Comment: How did you get the dump file, from a database ?

Comment: @NaveenKumar They are price feeds from my suppliers, in the form of csv and txt tab-deliminated

Comment: The problem is that the thousands separator is the same as fields delimiter. Therefore you have to change (preprocess your file) either of them **before** you import it with `LOAD DATA...`

Comment: Why have you escaped the `\r` with a double slash but not the `\n`? Surely they both need it?

Comment: @peterm So the fact that i used the replace statement makes no difference?

Comment: @user2231688 Yes it makes no difference because it happens after not before `LOAD DATA` splits a line

Comment: @peterm could you give me any hints on where to look for a solution to my problem. The thing is that all fields are quoted, ie "1,015.50" and seperated with comma, so i would have thought that it should import ok. I even tried creating a temp table with varchar on each column, which i would then use a replace function on and then copy to the real table, but no luck, its still not importing anything over 999.99.

Comment: @user2231688 If **all** fields are enclosed in double quotes, which you didn't mention in your question, then it might work. Can you post a sample file data (a few representative rows) and I can look into it.

Comment: @peterm please see my edit above, which includes a few lines of the file in question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your table looks something like

```
CREATE TABLE supplierimport 
(
distributorid int, 
MPN varchar(32),
description varchar(100),
description2 varchar(100),
customers_price decimal(19,2),
home_stock int,
brand_name varchar(100),
delivery_date date,
item_group_number varchar(32),
item_group_name varchar(100),
product_link varchar(255),
picture_link varchar(255),
barcode varchar(32),
weight decimal(19,4),
UNSPSC varchar(32),
product_type_code varchar(32),
warranty varchar(32)
);
```

This will allow you successfully load data

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/feed6.txt'
INTO TABLE supplierimport
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' -- or '\r\n' in your case
IGNORE 1 LINES
(MPN, @description, @description2, @customers_price, @home_stock, @brand_name, @delivery_date, 
 @item_group_number, @item_group_name, @product_link, @picture_link, @barcode, @weight, @UNSPSC, @product_type_code, @warranty)
SET distributorid = 546, 
    description       = NULLIF(@description, ''),
    description2      = NULLIF(@description2, ''),
    customers_price   = REPLACE(NULLIF(@customers_price), ',', ''), 
    home_stock        = NULLIF(@home_stock, ''), 
    brand_name        = NULLIF(@brand_name, ''), 
    delivery_date     = STR_TO_DATE(NULLIF(@delivery_date, ''), '%d/%m/%Y'), 
    item_group_number = NULLIF(@item_group_number, ''), 
    item_group_name   = NULLIF(@item_group_name, ''), 
    product_link      = NULLIF(@product_link, ''), 
    picture_link      = NULLIF(@picture_link, ''), 
    barcode           = NULLIF(@barcode, ''), 
    weight            = NULLIF(@weight, ''), 
    UNSPSC            = NULLIF(@UNSPSC, ''), 
    product_type_code = NULLIF(@product_type_code, ''), 
    warranty          = NULLIF(@warranty, '');
```

The result on my machine

```
mysql> select * from supplierimport;
+---------------+----------+-------------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------+------------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------------+--------+----------+-------------------+----------+
| distributorid | MPN      | description             | description2 | customers_price | home_stock | brand_name | delivery_date | item_group_number | item_group_name | product_link                                     | picture_link                                 | barcode       | weight | UNSPSC   | product_type_code | warranty |
+---------------+----------+-------------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------+------------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------------+--------+----------+-------------------+----------+
|           546 | /5PL0006 | Drum Unit               | DK-23        |          126.00 |         32 | Kyocera    | 2013-11-03    | 800002            | Drums           | http://uk.product.com/product.aspx?id=%2f5PL0006 | http://s.pic.eu/products/2_PICTURE-TAKEN.JPG | 5711045360824 | 0.3000 | 44103109 | NULL              | 3M       |
|           546 | /DK24    | DK-24 Drum Unit FS-3750 | NULL         |         1117.00 |          8 | Dell       | 2013-11-07    | 800002            | Drums           | http://uk.product.com/product.aspx?id=%2fDK24    | http://s.pic.eu/products/2_PICTURE-TAKEN.JPG | 5711045360718 | 0.2000 | 44103109 | NULL              | 3M       |
+---------------+----------+-------------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------+------------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------------+--------+----------+-------------------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this. Two things though, this sorted out the issue with the thousand seperator, although i had to add ", ''" onto nullif(@customersprice) bit. However, using n\ or \r\n both still only import exactly half. What happened is that it would miss alternate rows (2,4,6,8,10 etc) but it puts item number of the missed row within the warranty column of the previous row, if that makes sense. I finally tried using \r and it imported exactly double with null values for all columns for the double but at least i can use delete from where null type statment and then i have my rec